# Video from website to windows application

Tags: c#, .net, video, web

Who knows how to display the video from website in windows application?
[This is the site](http://fs.ua/)

I want to write an application to it. Can I do it without knowing API? Or if there is no API.
I will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say API? It should mean Application programming interface. If there is no API, you cannot use it anyway. Please rephrase: is there an API and you do not know it, or is there none?

Comment: I do not know. I wrote a letter to the site, but they have not yet responded. It seems to me they have no API. I think you can achieve something by using the [webBrowser component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way would be to use a WebBrowser control and use an embed link (if it exists) or parse the HTML to obtain the flash object with the correct parameters.

Comment: I would be very happy if someone could throw off the sample code for this site!

Comment: Well, the site is in Russian and I believe you require an account to watch any of the videos... I'll see if I can make an account and whip up a small example.

Comment: I'm very excited. Thank you my good man. You don't need a account to watch films.

Comment: I have no idea how to play anything. All I can see is the film description and user reviews...

Comment: I get: 404, Такой страницы на нашем сайте нет.
Попробуйте воспользоваться поиском.

Looks like it's not available outside Russia.

Comment: Maybe in your home country, there are similar sites?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they'd be different and wouldn't be exactly the same. Can't you just navigate to the video page with the WebBrowser control?

Comment: It displays the entire page. And I want to select only the video frame.

Comment: Yes, it just redirects back to the main page.